# No Constructor found when using PowerMockito for mocking JSONObject constructor

Tags: json, mockito, powermock

I'm using a custom class for JSONObject (madison.util.json.JSONObject) instead of the standard org.json.JSONObject and am trying to mock a constructor(String) call for JSONObject.class using PowerMockito.

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(JSONObject.class).withArguments(String.class).thenReturn(jsonStub);
```

I'm getting teh following error:

```
No constructor found in class 'madison.util.json.JSONObject' with parameter types: [ null ].
```

Can anybody advise what is the problem here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you pass a Class as argument not a String. 
To pass a string without take care of its value, you can use:

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(JSONObject.class).withArguments(Matchers.anyString()).thenReturn(jsonStub);
```

Otherwise, If you need a String.class as argument try:

```
whenNew(MimeMessage.class).withParameterTypes(MyParameterType.class).withArguments(isA(MyParameter.class)).thenReturn(mimeMessageMock);
```

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/powermock/ncH_2u39UBM/Rtk0-_FufzQJ